# Approaches for securing an HTML web app + Web API setup that needs to support SSO and Forms authentication

Tags: security, authentication, asp.net-web-api, forms-authentication, single-sign-on

We are building an application with following attributes:

- Consists of a web app, a web API, and mobile apps in future
- The web app will contain HTML pages (multiple features that behave
  like single pages applications)
- The web app will talk to the web API (communicates in JSON, using
  JQuery AJAX Calls)
- The web app + web API do not follow the standard MVC architecture
- Need to support SSO (will be using client Identity Provider) and
  forms authentication
- mobile will be consuming the same web API

My question is around what approach we should follow for securing the application. Two of the approaches that we are contemplating on are:

- Securing the web API only: the web app is purely HTML and all the
  data (that needs security) will come from the web API

  - For this, we thought of using OAuth for securing the web API
  - Both, the web app and the mobile app will first perform
    authentication, generate an access token (follow the OAuth flow)
- Securing the web app using forms authentication/SSO, and using HMAC
  authentication for authenticating the API consumer (web/mobile app)

  - This delegates the user authentication to the consumers (web and
    mobile app)
  - The API consumers will use HMAC for authenticating themselves
  - How can we pass the authenticated user details to the web API? Don’t
    want to pass it as a parameter in API calls

Or is there any other approach that is better than the ones we evaluated above? Has anyone handled a similar situation where an HTML web app uses a Web API, and authentication happens using SSO + Forms/custom authentication?

If you have any comments agreeing/disagreeing the two approaches, that would be welcome as well.

We understand that the web app cannot be purely HTML, and some of the SSO authentication part will have to be handled on the server side and that is ok. But the core application will be HTML + Web API.

Here is some additional information related to this:
 - Using ASP.Net with Framework 4.0 (with VS2010 IDE)
 - Using Web API 1, but open to switch to Web API 2

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from building an external authentication/authorization identity management component in your architecture.  Your current use cases can probably be covered by the tools that come with ASP.NET, but the architecture will be hard to extend as you start adding different types of clients and SSO scenarios.  Look at [this](http://leastprivilege.com/2013/11/13/authorization-servers-are-good-for-you-and-your-web-apis/) and [this](http://leastprivilege.com/2014/03/24/the-web-api-v2-oauth2-authorization-server-middlewareis-it-worth-it/)  articles for a more detailed explanation.

Azure ID and Access management offering can be a good option.  If you don't want to use the cloud, there are some third party and open source identity servers available.

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff423674.aspx) is a good free book to help you understand federated identity concepts in the context of Microsoft technologies.